# getimagesize failed to open stream connection timed out

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На одном компьютере регулярно возникает эта проблема, не могу понять почему она возникает. На других компьютерах вроде подобных проблем нет.

И ещё, если убрать getimagesize,  то эта же ошибка повторится на copy?

Может чем то можно заменить getimagesize? я его использую чтобы определить формат файла по ссылке, чтобы загружать только картинки трех форматов.

Comment: У вас проблема не в данной функции, а в доступе к файлу. Вы его сначала к себе на сервер скачайте.

Comment: @Visman а как тогда определить формат файла чтобы его скачать ? Ведь у некоторый url нет расширения никакого, чтобы скачать и найти файл потом, я должен ему имя присвоить с расширением, а так скачается непонятный  файл с неизвестным именем и расширением

Comment: Закачиваете файл к себе на сервер, определяете формат через getimagesize(), переименовываете с нужным именем. Если закачиваете через curl, то с его помощью смотрите заголовки ответа сервера с которого файл качаете.

Comment: $filename = $_FILES['video_file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: @Visman смотрю заголовок ответа сервера через функцию get_headers, но также ошибка failed to open stream connection timed out

Comment: @DanielProtopopov я так понял вы написали как найти скаченный файл, но я не могу понять как скачать файл не указывая его нового имени и расширения

Comment: Единственное что остается это по последним 3-4 символам смотреть расширение, скачивать, проверять. Но это не будет работать на ссылках без расширения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что адрес сервера на котором расположен мой проект, был заблокирован на сайте к которому я пытался обратится, поэтому ничерта не работало